# Passing data from Native Activity to WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, string, android-studio

I am trying to pass a String using an Intent from my Native Activity and retrieve it in my WebActivity class like this:

```java
final String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");
```

After that, I am trying to call a Javascript function that will use DOM Manipulation to change the value of a `text` input to the `username` value from the Intent. My problem is:

This works (hardcoded value called "test"):

```js
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('username').value = 'test';})();");
```

This doesn't (trying to set it to my intent value):

```js
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('username').value = "+username+";})();");
```

I assume maybe I'm wrapping the `username` value incorrectly, but using it the way I have it now doesn't modify the text input at all.

Comment: I don't know much about JavaScript, but you're missing the single quotes around the value in the second snippet; i.e., `...value = '"+username+"';})();"`

Comment: I tried that, but the value it gets set to is `null`

Comment: Well, that would seem to indicate that the JavaScript is working, then. There's just a problem with putting or getting the extra, or maybe you are just passing a null value there.

Comment: I figured it out. It was my fault. When I was creating the `Intent`, I called the `startActivity()` function _before_ calling the `putExtra()` function

Comment: But thank you for clarifying the missing single quotes, that also was something I missed.

Answer (score 0):

With help from user [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) I was able to see there were two mistakes I was making:

- Incorrectly putting the extra
- Missing single quotes

```java
Intent myWebIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyWebActivity.class);
myWebIntent.putExtra("USERNAME", s); // this line needs to go before startActivity()
startActivity(battleShipIntent);
```

The `username` value should be wrapped in single quotes like so:

```java
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('username').value = '"+username+"';})();");
```